# SNMP from the browser

Tags: flash, silverlight-4.0, snmp

There"s this idea of having a web app search for devices in the network (with elevated user permissions, of course).

Checking the silverlight and flash APIs, there does not seem to be a way to do SNMP ( the UDP APIs are limited to multicasting media ).

Anyone know a clever workaround? In windows, a small XBAP utility can do the SNMP stuff, but that leaves out the Mac OS X platform.

Thanks for any ideas.

*( I do have a SO account but I"m in a not so trustworthy public PC right now so I didn"t log in. )*

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use Silverlight to build the representation level. The SNMP heavy tasks can be separated into a WCF application running in the background.